# how do I change the default pagesize?

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

How do I change the default page-size of CRUD? YII framework default displays 10 results, how to change display limit?

`controllers/UsersController.php`

```
class UsersController extends Controller{
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';

    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }


    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Users']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model=new Users('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Users']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Users'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Users::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='users-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

`view/users/admin.php`

```
/* @var $this UsersController */
/* @var $model Users */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Users'=>array('index'),
    'Manage',
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List Users', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create Users', 'url'=>array('create')),
);

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
    $('.search-form').toggle();
    return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $('#users-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
");
?>

<h1>Manage Users</h1>

<p>
You may optionally enter a comparison operator (<b>&lt;</b>, <b>&lt;=</b>, <b>&gt;</b>, <b>&gt;=</b>, <b>&lt;&gt;</b>
or <b>=</b>) at the beginning of each of your search values to specify how the comparison should be done.
</p>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
    'model'=>$model,
)); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'users-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'pass',
        'config',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

**Edit**:

How to choose only the first 5 we recorded?

Comment: What `the first 5 we recorded` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Users` Model check the `search()` method

```
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
            $criteria->compare('pass',$this->pass,true);

    .......
            .......
            .......         

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Here you can set/configure the `pagination` property. `pagination` is the property of `CActiveDataProvider` class which can return the object of CPagination class.

You can set the page size

```
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
                    'pagination'=>array('pageSize' => 20),
    ));
```

Or

```
            $pageSize=20;
            $pagination = new CPagination($pageSize);
            return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
                    'pagination'=>$pagination

     ));
```

Comment: how to choose only the first 5 we recorded ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Model, change the `search()` method, where it returns the CActiveDataProvider:

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
     'criteria'=>$criteria,
     'pagination' => array(
         'pageSize' => 40,
     ),
));
```

Comment: and how to choose only the first 5 we recorded ? Do you have some tutorial to create dashboard? which I substituted for criteria?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['activity_id' => SORT_DESC]],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 10, 
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.